# How can i fix this stupid python syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I keep getting this stupid syntax error. Solving this error could be the last thing i need before i can finally upgrade my pc and get a gpu. Syntax error line 28

File "autobot.py", line 28
except:
^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**I get the syntax error when i try to run the script**
This syntax error is very annoying

Im just trying to create a bot that will add a GPU to my cart because its my last resort to actually get a card. All these scalpers are annoying so im just gonna make my own bot to buy me one gpu.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
# For Using Chrome
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/matthewsievenpiper/vhromedriver')

# Bestbuy Founder Edition RTX 3080 Page
browser.get('https://www.bestbuy.com/site/nvidia-geforce-rtx-3080-10gb-gddr6x-pci-express-4-0-graphics-card-titanium-and-black/6429440.p?skuId=6429440')

# Bestbuy purchaseable page
#browser.get('https://www.bestbuy.com/site/seagate-barracuda-2tb-internal-sata-hard-drive-for-desktops/6344172.p?skuId=6344172')


buyButton = False 

while not buyButton:

    try:
        #If this works then button is not pytopen
        addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-disabled")

        # Button isnt open restart the script
        print("Button isn't ready yet.")

        # Refresh page after delay
        time.sleep(1)
        browser.refresh()
line 28  except:
        
        addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-primary")

        # Click the button and end the script
        print("Button was clicked!")
        addToCartBtnbuyButton.click()
        buyButton = True
```

Comment: except should be on the same indent as try.

Comment: please post the code as you have it, but number the line with a comment (otherwise we don't know what is the actual indentation). also fix the backticks at the end of your code

Comment: The error is not stupid. If the interpreter says you have a syntax error, *then you do*. The interpreter is always right in this regard, because it is an operational definition of correct syntax. Take a deep breath, force down your irritation, and look carefully at where the caret `^` is pointing. The error is either at or before before where it points.

Answer (score 0):

Mind the indentation.

`except` should be at the same line indentation as `try`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver 
# For Using Chrome
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/matthewsievenpiper/vhromedriver')

# Bestbuy Founder Edition RTX 3080 Page
browser.get('https://www.bestbuy.com/site/nvidia-geforce-rtx-3080-10gb-gddr6x-pci-express-4-0-graphics-card-titanium-and-black/6429440.p?skuId=6429440')

# Bestbuy purchaseable page
#browser.get('https://www.bestbuy.com/site/seagate-barracuda-2tb-internal-sata-hard-drive-for-desktops/6344172.p?skuId=6344172')


buyButton = False 

while not buyButton:

    try:
        #If this works then button is not pytopen
        addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-disabled")

        # Button isnt open restart the script
        print("Button isn't ready yet.")

        # Refresh page after delay
        time.sleep(1)
        browser.refresh()
    except: # should be at same line as 'try'
        
        addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-primary")

        # Click the button and end the script
        print("Button was clicked!")
        addToCartBtnbuyButton.click()
        buyButton = True
```